How can I find out from which object the event was called?
I want the event to work only on mouse click, how can this happen?
I use jqwitgets grid, this event I use for the grid is triggered when I select a row with the mouse.
$(document).on("rowselect", "#jqxgrid", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
});

but this rowselect is triggered again on an input event
$('#INPUT_NAME').off('keyup');
$(document).on("keyup", "#INPUT_NAME", function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('selectrow', 0);
    $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('focus');
});

  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('selectrow', 0);


This line in the input event triggers the grid rowselect event, I want to prevent this.
thank you
$(document).on("rowselect", ".grid", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if(e.type == "keyup")
 return false;

I used e.stopImmediatePropagation(); but still "rowselect" is triggered.
When I look with e.type, it shows the triggering of the current event e.type="rowselect" but I need the type of the previous event, ie e.type="keyup" but I could not find the previous type
keyup is an example. Many events like this affect the "rowselect"  event.
and my last question
why does rowunselect run automatically after the rowselect event when I select the row with the mouse? how can I prevent this?
I added e.stopImmediatePropagation(); but it didn't work thanks
jsfiddle

Consider the following:
https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/z2emuvt7/
JavaScript
 $("#jqxgrid").on("mousedown mouseup click rowselect rowunselect", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   console.log(e.type);
 });

Results
mousedown
rowselect
rowunselect
mouseup
click

You can see here, that multiple events are triggered when the User selects a row. This includes click event. Without digging too deep, I am guessing that there are a bunch of things tied to mousedown and mouseup related to selection and dragging.
I do not see a good way to accomplish what you want to do.
